# How to change mac address of 3G/4G mobile broadband device?

Tags: mobile, mac-address, 3g, 4g, broadband

I am trying to use [technitium tmac](https://technitium.com/tmac/). But it just doesn't work.

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: I've been trying to do that from C# program.

Comment: Then I recommend you [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Because right now the question seems very off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to do this programatically, so it is programming related as Joachim notes, then I think you are going to have problems doing it with this software. They note in some of their own feedback on comments that it does not support 3G etc:

> ... TMAC can change MAC address only for Ethernet & WiFi networks.

From: http://blog.technitium.com/2011/05/tmac-issue-with-wireless-network.html

It might be worth explain more what you are trying to do as the IMSI is normally the key identifier on a Mobile network so it would help to explain what you are aiming to do by changing the MAC address.